How Flexmonster get data from elasticsearch?
I'm using Flexmonster to connect to my local elasticsearch indices, but would like to know how that happens. In particular I don't understand how it can load all the data and not the first 10k records as an usual "http://localhost:9200/index/_search?size=10000" would work.
When I run a query (a simple count on a field just to know how many records it reads) there are two network requests:


Both of them use URL: "http://localhost:9200/jolanda_map/_search" and retrive all the dataset because the query shows me the exact number of records (2.7 millions). So:

Why if I use that same URL i just get the first 10 records?
Why there are two requests (one with "OPTIONS" method, and one with "POST" method)?
If I would replicate what Fleximonster does, getting all record in my dataset (rather than first 10 or 10k), how could I do?


The OPTIONS request is a part of CORS/same-site-requests... has to do with requests made across ports or domains and is something the browser automatically does ahead of any other HTTP request to check with the server if the client app/domain/port is "allowed" to make requests and what HTTP methods are allowed.

Recommend right click on that network request and "copy as curl" paste that into vs-code or a CLI if have git bash or powershell it should work file in those (copy as curl bash if using bash).  You can grab a vs-code extension called "REST client" or use POSTMan to have some sort of nicer interface to send requests without working in the browser all the time and that won't do the OPTIONS requests but this is normal CORS stuff in the browser if cross domain or port.

Thanks, this really helped me understanding better. Just a question: the difference is in the REST API? I mean if i use http://localhost:9200/index/_search in my browser it just reads first 10 documents, while if i use Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "http://localhost:9200/jolanda_map/_search" in the powershell it doesn't. Where is the difference?
